# HTML5 Input pattern for date

Tags: html, regex, forms, input

My attempt:

```
  Year <select ng-options="x for x in ['2018']" required>      </select> 
  Month: <input  pattern="[0-1][0-9]" maxlength="2"   required></input> 
  Day: <input  pattern="[0-3][0-9]" maxlength="2"   required></input>
```

Create input box for Year, Month, and Day , which has following input validation. Do you have any suggestion for the HTML5 input form pattern which accepts the following parameters?

- Year [2018]
- Month [01-12]
- Day [01-31] for Month [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
- Day [01-30] for Month [4,6,9,11]
- Day [01-28] for Month [2]

Can the following condition  be added to the input pattern.

- if month 1 is selected, input box for the day allows 1-31,
- if month 2 is selected, input box for the day allows 1-28

Comment: can't you use a javascript calendar/date picker?

Comment: can i use JS date picker inside angularJS? The input box is written in angular controller

Answer (score 1):

Here are some patterns for your requested dates. However, I do not think it is possible to solve the condition with regex only, so you might need a HTML/Js solution for this.

```
(1\d{3}|2\d{3}) //Matches all the years between 1000 and 2999
(0[1-9]|1[0-2]) //Matches all numbers from 01 to 12
([0-2]\d|3[0-1])//Matches days from 01 to 31
([0-2]\d|30)    //Matches days from 01 to 30
([0-1]\d|2[0-8])//Matches days from 01 to 28
```